# MapBox GL JS - How to set polygon Z-ordering within a layer

Tags: mapbox

I would like to set the Z-ordering of the polygons on my MapBox GL JS vectortile layer. There is a "category" attribute with values: 1 and 2. Polygons with category 2 should be on the top.

This is the definiton of my layer:

```
map.addLayer({
  'id': 'testLayer',
  'type': 'fill',
  'source': 'testSource','source-layer': 'polygons',
      "paint": {
'fill-color':   {    "property": "cat",
          "type": "categorical",
          "stops": [
            [1, "#8dd3c7"],
            [2, "#ffffb3"]
          ]}
    }
});
```

How can I set Z ordering?

I'vew find this: https://docs.mapbox.com/help/troubleshooting/optimize-map-label-placement/

Order of features inside layers:

The draw order of features inside a single vector tileset source layer can be specified
At runtime with symbol-sort-key: If you don't have control over the data at the time of tileset creation, you can influence the draw order of features at runtime using symbol-sort-key.

How to use it? I don't know the syntax and I didn't find any examples.